# Iterate through a CSV file and get every value for a specified header?

Tags: php, xml, csv, dom

I have a CSV file and I want to check if the row contains a special title. Only if my row contains a special title it should be converted to XML, other stuff added and so on.

My question now is, how can I iterate through the whole CSV file and get for every title the value in this field?

Because if it matches my special title I just want to convert the specified row where the title is matching my title. Maybe also an idea how I can do that?

Sample: [CSV File](http://www.onlinekeystore.com/feed.php?key=GmYAQ4RcndpD3aPkjnWkJf4r&dl)

I must add that feature to my actual function. Because my actual function is just is converting the whole CSV to XML. But I just want to convert the specified rows.

My actual function:

```
function csvToXML($inputFilename, $outputFilename, $delimiter = ',')
{
  // Open csv to read
  $inputFile = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

  // Get the headers of the file
  $headers = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter);

  // Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
  $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $doc->formatOutput = true;

  // Add a root node to the document
  $root = $doc->createElement('products');
  $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

  // Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
  while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {
    $container = $doc->createElement('product');
    foreach ($headers as $i => $header) {
      $child = $doc->createElement($header);
      $child = $container->appendChild($child);
      $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
      $value = $child->appendChild($value);
    }

    $root->appendChild($container);
  }

  $strxml = $doc->saveXML();
  $handle = fopen($outputFilename, 'w');
  fwrite($handle, $strxml);
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the title before adding the rows to XML.  You could do it by adding the following lines:

```
 while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {

    $specialTitles = Array('Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3'); // titles you want to keep

    if(in_array($row[1], $specialTitles)){
        $container = $doc->createElement('product');
        foreach ($headers as $i => $header) {
          $child = $doc->createElement($header);
          $child = $container->appendChild($child);
          $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
          $value = $child->appendChild($value);
        }

        $root->appendChild($container);
    }
  }
```

Comment: But why `$row[1]`?

Comment: `fgetcsv` returns an array of the fields from the CSV line.  Since your `Title` is in the second column, it should be @ index 1.

Comment: I got it :D - But I have no idea why my IDE is not accepting my code...
Without if it is accepted??? Picture.. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzLxINxZFzova2dDYm50YkplWTg

Comment: you are missing a closing `)` on your `if` statement..!

Comment: ha ha, I was missing a closing `)`.  Updated my answer..!

Comment: Yeah, Thank You! - I forgot this post by coding... But at the moment I have another problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136296/discussion-between-bizzybob-and-jan).